# Phoenix error: module not loaded/not available

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following the Programming Phoenix book, working on the section to implement logging in/out an authenticated user, and am receiving an error I don't know what to do with:

```
mix phoenix.server
Compiled lib/rumbl.ex
Compiled lib/rumbl/repo.ex
Compiled web/channels/user_socket.ex
Compiled web/web.ex
Compiled web/models/user.ex

== Compilation error on file web/router.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Rumbl.Auth.init/1 (module Rumbl.Auth is not available)
    Rumbl.Auth.init([repo: Rumbl.Repo])
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:198: Plug.Builder.init_module_plug/3
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:186: anonymous fn/4 in Plug.Builder.compile/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1387: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:186: Plug.Builder.compile/3
    web/router.ex:4: (module)
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:669: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file lib/rumbl/endpoint.ex ==
** (UndefinedFunctionError) undefined function: Rumbl.Router.init/1 (module Rumbl.Router is not available)
    Rumbl.Router.init([])
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:198: Plug.Builder.init_module_plug/3
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:186: anonymous fn/4 in Plug.Builder.compile/3
    (elixir) lib/enum.ex:1387: Enum."-reduce/3-lists^foldl/2-0-"/3
    (plug) lib/plug/builder.ex:186: Plug.Builder.compile/3
    (phoenix) expanding macro: Phoenix.Endpoint.__before_compile__/1
    lib/rumbl/endpoint.ex:1: Rumbl.Endpoint (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/views/user_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/user_view.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/views/user_view.ex:2: Rumbl.UserView (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/views/user_view.ex:2: Rumbl.UserView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/views/error_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/error_view.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/views/error_view.ex:2: Rumbl.ErrorView (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/views/error_view.ex:2: Rumbl.ErrorView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/controllers/auth.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/auth.ex:3: module Comeonin.Bcypt is not loaded and could not be found
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:669: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/controllers/user_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/user_controller.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/controllers/user_controller.ex:2: Rumbl.UserController (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/controllers/user_controller.ex:2: Rumbl.UserController (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/controllers/page_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/page_controller.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/controllers/page_controller.ex:2: Rumbl.PageController (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/controllers/page_controller.ex:2: Rumbl.PageController (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/views/session_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/session_view.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/views/session_view.ex:2: Rumbl.SessionView (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/views/session_view.ex:2: Rumbl.SessionView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/views/page_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/page_view.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/views/page_view.ex:2: Rumbl.PageView (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/views/page_view.ex:2: Rumbl.PageView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/views/layout_view.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/views/layout_view.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/views/layout_view.ex:2: Rumbl.LayoutView (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/views/layout_view.ex:2: Rumbl.LayoutView (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8


== Compilation error on file web/controllers/session_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/session_controller.ex:2: module Rumbl.Router.Helpers is not loaded and could not be found
    expanding macro: Rumbl.Web.__using__/1
    web/controllers/session_controller.ex:2: Rumbl.SessionController (module)
    (elixir) expanding macro: Kernel.use/2
    web/controllers/session_controller.ex:2: Rumbl.SessionController (module)
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:100: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/8
```

I've checked and double checked my code against the book, but can't see anything.
My files for the project are here: https://github.com/bordeltabernacle/learning-phoenix/tree/master/rumbl

As far as I can tell the `Rumbl.Auth.init` function is there in the `auth.ex` controller file, and I'm not sure what the `Rumbl.Router.Helpers` file is or how to load it.  When i remove the only new line in the `router.ex` file, since the app was working, I get the same error.
I'm afraid I don't yet know enough to troubleshoot this myself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've got typo in `https://github.com/bordeltabernacle/learning-phoenix/blob/master/rumbl/web/controllers/auth.ex`

```
import Comeonin.Bcypt, only: [checkpw: 2]
```

should be

```
import Comeonin.Bcrypt, only: [checkpw: 2]
```

Answer (score 24):

I think you should try to clean up deps, then get and compile again before up sever

so try

```
mix deps.clean --all
mix deps.get
mix deps.compile
mix phoenix.server
```

Good luck

Comment: Doing `mix deps.compile` helped me with my view modules not being detected anymore.

Comment: Also delete all the folders inside deps before execute the above commands, that could help

Answer (score 1):

You could also delete the `_build` directory and restart your server with `mix phoenix.server` (Phoenix 1.2) or `mix phx.server` (Phoenix 1.3).

Doing this will fetch all dependencies from scratch for the first time. I prefer this method as I don't need to type a bunch of commands, I just need to delete a directory and re-run the recent command on my terminal..which is `mix phx.server`. Yeah, I'm lazy.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this error happened because I accidentally created a module in the `test` directory instead of the `lib` directory. Moving it to the `lib` directory fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

In my umbrella project, I added a new `support` directory within the `tests` directory and the `.ex` modules within were not accessible to my tests.

By default, mix looks only within the `lib` directory for files to compile. You can add another directory by adding [elixirc_paths](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Protocol.html#module-consolidation) to `project` in your `mix.exs`.